# Ceph limitations (number of buckets and number of users)

Tags: bucket, ceph, radosgw

I want to know about these questions:

1. maximum number of buckets in ceph cluster
2. maximum number of users in radosgw

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**maximum number of buckets in ceph cluster**: The default limit for buckets per user in Ceph is 1000, but it is adjustable. You can set it to any number you want. In fact, you can even have an unlimited number of buckets by setting max user buckets to 0.

**Recommendation and Limitations**: It is better not to go beyond a few thousand buckets per user. Because you may end up with a huge number of buckets per user, and at that point listing buckets may just take too long. The list of buckets per user resides on a single object and is not striped, therefore a really high number of buckets would be a problem as you will probably end up with an unbalanced data allocation. Another issue is that the bucket listing API does not work in chunks, therefore, for every request you will end up getting the entire list of buckets, which will cause issues.